# Can one accept Muhammad and remain Jewish?

Tags: navi-prophets, islam

On the premise that one who accepts the Torah as Moses delivered it to us from Mount Sinai, and considering that Islam considers the Tanach as a holy book, can one accept Muhammad as a prophet and remain Jewish?

In addition to the Torah, we include works after Moses such as Neviim and Ktuvim in the Tanach. Why might someone / some sect not accept the Quran as well? Even during and after the time of the rise of Islam did the Jews add to the store of holy books, ie Gamara and Talmud.

I understand that the Jews originally rejected Muhammad as a prophet due to his campaign for political control. However that seems to be a technical rejection, not a philosophical rejection.

Comment: Jews think camel is not a kosher animal. Do you? Our Torah says so explicitly ([Leviticus 11:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0311.htm#4)).

Comment: Doesn't matter what _I_ think. Are you suggesting that so long as one refrains from eating camel, he can believe in Muhammad and still be Jewish?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is it because this is a politically-sensitive question? If the question could be improved I would appreciate to know how.

Comment: I'm suggesting that anyone who tells you the two books are compatible doesn't know what each contains. That's all that needs to be said here. No you can't be Muslim and Jewish.

Comment: Nobody told me anything, I'm asking exactly _what_ is incompatible. So far I've learned that camel is off the plate. That's great! If all that needs to be done to reconcile the two faiths is to refrain from a few simple actions (such as eating camel) and there are no mutually-exclusive requirements / restrictions, then the faiths could be reconciled. This is a thought experiment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "remain Jewish," but here are some possible duplicates: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33467 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29341 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28825. Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28694 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26745.

Comment: Thank you Fred! Here is another relevant one, just for demonstrating that one can adhere to two faiths simultaneously: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40845/is-buddhism-avodah-zarah

Comment: @dotancohen The top answer there indicates that a Jew cannot adhere to Judaism and Buddhism simultaneously. Regarding Islam specifically, see my comments [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26342/did-the-rambam-say-its-ok-for-a-jew-to-convert-to-islam#comment59710_26352) and [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26342/did-the-rambam-say-its-ok-for-a-jew-to-convert-to-islam#comment59713_26352).

Comment: @dotancohen It's not just a few actions. It's a philosophy that two contradictory texts are both Divine.

Comment: As an example, Mohammed pretended that Yishmael was the subject of the Akeidah and put statements in the koran that explicitly contradicted the Torah.

Comment: This question's a bit unclear but it seems to be a duplicate of one of the posts @Fred linked to above; I've closed it as a duplicate of the one that seems to me most likely your intent.

Comment: Islam teaches that the torah that God gave us at Sinai is somehow corrupt, and Islam rewrites parts of it (e.g. to say that it was Yismael who was almost offered on Moriah).  Further, as I understand it, Islam considers Jesus to be a prophet, while we do not.  And, of course, Muhammad is not.  So there are rather a few important differences; one professing faith in both Islam and Judaism must either be unaware of such problems or willing to ignore them, and in neither religion is the latter OK as best I understand.

Comment: I think this is a good question. While I agree it has been asked before, none of the duplicate questions provide anything close to a serious answer.

Comment: @SAH The OP can add a bounty there if he wishes. See the help center: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two questions here: the one you asked and the one you intended to ask. To answer the question that you asked, even if someone accepts Mohammad as a prophet, he remains Jewish. Nothing can remove a person's Jewishness. Once one is Jewish, he is Jewish forever, no matter how many sins he commits.

In response to the question you intended to ask, believing in Mohammad as a prophet and believing in Judaism are incompatible. It is [impossible for a prophet to change the commandments in the Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26426/1713). If someone tries to do that, it *proves* that he is a false prophet. As is mentioned in the comments on the question, the Quran as revealed by Mohammad permits eating camel. Since this is explicitly prohibited in the Torah, it proves that Mohammad is a false prophet. This is just one example of statements in the Quran that contradict the Torah. Each and every one of those contradictions is sufficient to dismiss the possibility of Mohammad's prophethood.

Comment: Where in the Quran is eating camel stated to be permitted? It's a rather thin thread of reasoning to use such assumptions to justify your a priori beliefs. See 28:48-50 where the Quran and Torah are put on an equal footing: following either is satisfactory in the Quranic view. The views of Muslims, medieval or modern, are a different matter entirely.